# Shifting bits for multiplication MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, bit-shift

I'm writing a MIPS assemble language program to perform multiplicate by shifting bits using the 'sll' operation.
Here's my source code:

```
    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    ori     $5,$0,2     # put x into $5
    ori     $6,$0,4        # put y into $6
    sll     $5,$5,3        # put 8*x into $8
    sll     $6,$6,1        # put 2*y into $9
    subu    $10,$8,$9      # $5 - $6, put result in 10
    addiu   $10,$10,14     # add register 10 and number 14, put result in 10
```

### End of file

My "sll $5, $5, 3 " line should be taking the contents of register 5 and multiplying it by 2^3 then placing it back into register 5. Instead of displaying 16, it displays 10. My guess is that the three bit shift it's performing is causing an overflow problem, but I can't think of a way to correct this.

Comment: Your comments for `sll` instructions don't seem to agree with the code.

Comment: There would only be overflow if the register is less than 5 bits wide.

Comment: Is it possible you're displaying the result in hex? 16 decimal is 10 hex.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I was displaying the register values in hex. Appreciate it!